# How to center span over image while maintaining mouseover functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="pic">

    <img src="image.jpg" height="250"/>
    <span class="text" style="display:none">text here</span>

</div>

<scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('img').css('opacity', 0.4);
    $('img').next('span.text').show();

    $('img').bind('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).css('opacity', 1.0);
        $(this).next('span.text').hide();
    });
    $('img').bind('mouseout', function () {
        $(this).css('opacity', 0.3);
        $(this).next('span.text').show();
    });

</script>
```

I have an opaque image that becomes fully visible on `mouseover`. I added text with span that would disappear on `mouseover` and reappear on `mouseout` similarly to the opaqueness on the image. I tried to center the text with `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` in CSS, but lacked results. Is there a way to center the text while still having the opaqueness and the text disappear on `mouseover`? Is Javascript the best way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to attach the mouseover etc to the div rather than image?

Comment: I would also recommend to use the div for the mouseover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you do this with CSS?

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.pic {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position:relative;
}
.pic img {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
.text {
  opacity: 1;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
.pic:hover img {
  opacity: 1;

}
.pic:hover .text {
  opacity: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="pic">

  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-250-7.jpg" />
  <span class="text">text here</span>

</div>
```